# how to remove AdminLte popup "You load Adminlte demo.js.This file is only created for a testing purpose"?

Tags: angular, adminlte

I have used the AdminLte theme in my angular project. But after deployment, pop-up is showing 'You load Adminlte demo.js.This file is only created for a testing purpose". How to get rid of this? whenever I try to access the website. this popup comes. which is not a good sign.
please help me to remove this.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to find and remove these line.

```html
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<script src="/adminlte/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).